# How do you make the open form the only one that is selectable?

Tags: vb.net, forms

How do I make it so that a VB.net form that is opened from another form (say a settings form) is the only one that can be selected?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, and I can't see any obvious tools for this, but I'm not sure what I'm looking for. I have tried various possibilities like `TopMost = True`, but that is not quite it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of [`Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd.aspx) to open the new form.

This will open the form as a [modal dialog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window), and while it is open, no other form can be selected by the user.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Glad I know for the future, as I'm bound to need this again.